# C: Mudar cor de letras (várias cores em uma só tela)

Tags: c, windows, cores

Por exemplo, quero *printar* na mesma tela:

```
printf(".___. .___. .___.\n");

printf("._1_. ._2_. ._3_.\n");

printf("Digite 0 p/ sair ou outro número p/ continuar: ");
```

porém quero que as letras de cada `printf` fiquem com cores diferentes, por exemplo: primeiro o azul, depois o verde e depois o amarelo... Tentei usar o seguinte código:

```
system("color A");
printf(".___. .___. .___.\n");
system("color E");  
printf("._1_. ._2_. ._3_.\n");
system("color 7");   
printf("Digite 0 p/ sair ou outro número p/ continuar: ");
```

Porém não funcionou; ele pegou somente a última cor, ou melhor, ele foi rápido e só executou visivelmente a última cor... Tentei também:

```
#include <conio.h>
textcolor(blue);
printf(".___. .___. .___.\n");
textcolor(red); 
printf("._1_. ._2_. ._3_.\n");
textcolor(yellow);  
printf("Digite 0 p/ sair ou outro número p/ continuar: ");
```

Mas fala que `textcolor` não foi declarada.

Comment: Rapaz, `conio` é obsoleta demaisssZzzZzzZ.... Que tal [essa resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23657072/4056678) no SOen?

Comment: não funcionou, só printou um monte de caracter estranho, esse acho que é para o Unix (Linux)

Comment: ops, windows [bem aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9203489/4056678).

Comment: Deu certo, porém é meio complicado kk pois não posso usar função, vou ter que usar o system("color XX") mesmo, mas valeu a dica, em outros projetos eu uso esse

Comment: Experimenta se o teu ecra faz ["ANSI escape sequences"](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php): `printf("\x1b[32mHello\n");`

Comment: Se estás em Windows, talvez experimentar [ansicon](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon) funcione *(nunca experimentei)*

Comment: Esses só funcionam no Linux, e o ansicon só muda o cursor etc

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma fácil de fazer isso em C é usar o código ANSI das cores. No início você cria uma constante para armazenar o [ANSI para cada cor](https://gist.github.com/chrisopedia/8754917):

```
#define ANSI_COLOR_RED      "\x1b[31m" //cores em ANSI utilizadas 
#define ANSI_COLOR_GRAY     "\e[0;37m"
```

E para usar, passa essas constantes no `printf`:

```
printf(ANSI_COLOR_RED "Hello world" ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
```

Sendo que o primeiro é a cor que você deseja para esse texto, e no final você pode usar o Reset para voltar ao padrão.

[Aqui](https://github.com/leilaapsilva/pokemon-terminal/blob/master/jogo.cpp) tem um exemplo em que usei isso em um jogo.

Answer (score 0):

Já que você está procurando uma solução específica em C para windows, eu recomendaria usar a função `SetConsoleTextAttribute()` da API win32.
Você tem que gerar um *handler* para o terminal e então alimenta-lo com os atributos corretos.

Segue um exemplo simples:

```
/* Mudar a cor do texto do terminal, e depois de volta ao normal. */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO consoleInfo;
    WORD saved_attributes;

    /* Salvar estado atual */
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConsole, &consoleInfo);
    saved_attributes = consoleInfo.wAttributes;

    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUND_BLUE);
    printf("This is some nice COLORFUL text, isn't it?");

    /* Voltando ao estado original */
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, saved_attributes);
    printf("Back to normal");

    return 0;
}
```

Para mais informações (em inglês), olhe [aqui](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_character_attributes).